# Bootstrap floating elements to right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my bootstrap.css file for the navbar

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

In my navbar I have 4 eleements -

```
1) Search
2) Help
3) Logout
4) Feedback
```

I need to float the "search" element to left and all other elements to right.

How can I make the changes?

Comment: Give search a special class so you can target it differently from the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using LESS adding the .pull-right(); / .pull-left(); mixins should get you what you're looking for.

Things to consider:
 1. The example below targets the first li element with `:first-child`
 2. Your DOM may include class names, e.g. `.search, .help, etc..` so that's an option as-well. You would just replace `:first-child` with the class you want to target.
 3. Check the width of your .navbar-nav class. If it doesn't cover the width of the list elements it's not going to work out.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    .pull-right();
    &:first-child {
      .pull-left();
    }
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS might be helpful for you. This way search element will be on left side and rest of items will be on right side. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yajohifa/1/edit)** first.

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    text-align:right;
  }

  .navbar-nav > li {
     display: inline-block;
  }

.navbar-nav li:first-child 
  {
   float:left;
}
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Careful using pull-right on your navbar you will get unpredictable results.

According to Bootstrap documentation using navbar-right instead of pull-right

[See components here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Answer (score -2):

Use pull-left and pull-right classes

Comment: For navbar you should use navbar-right, not pull-right. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar